# How resolve hadoop installation error: hdfs namenode -format

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I installed hadoop on centos7. when i execute the command: `hdfs namenode -format`
I have an output with errors I tried several proposals that I saw on the internet but the problem is not solved.

```
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map cachedBlocks
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO util.GSet: 0.25% max memory 889 MB = 2.2 MB
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^18 = 262144 entries
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.window.num.buckets = 10
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.num.users = 10
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.windows.minutes = 1,5,25
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 889 MB = 273.1 KB
21/06/16 14:15:01 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory /storage/name ? (Y or N) y
21/06/16 14:15:06 WARN net.DNS: Unable to determine local hostname -falling back to "localhost"
java.net.UnknownHostException: LSHDP
localhost: LSHDP
localhost: Temporary failure in name resolution
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1506)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.resolveLocalHostname(DNS.java:264)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.<clinit>(DNS.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newBlockPoolID(NNStorage.java:966)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newNamespaceInfo(NNStorage.java:575)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:991)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1554)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: LSHDP
localhost: Temporary failure in name resolution
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1501)
        ... 8 more
21/06/16 14:15:06 WARN net.DNS: Unable to determine address of the host-falling back to "localhost" address
java.net.UnknownHostException: LSHDP
localhost: LSHDP
localhost: Temporary failure in name resolution
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1506)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.resolveLocalHostIPAddress(DNS.java:287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.<clinit>(DNS.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newBlockPoolID(NNStorage.java:966)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newNamespaceInfo(NNStorage.java:575)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:991)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1554)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: LSHDP
localhost: Temporary failure in name resolution
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1501)
        ... 8 more
21/06/16 14:15:06 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-352354458-127.0.0.1-1623852906859
21/06/16 14:15:06 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /storage/name has been successfully formatted.
21/06/16 14:15:07 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
21/06/16 14:15:07 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
21/06/16 14:15:07 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at java.net.UnknownHostException: LSHDP
localhost: LSHDP
localhost: Temporary failure in name resolution
************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your DNS server (or OS hosts file) such that a host named `LSHDP` is known.

For example, `ping LSHDP` should return you a similar error

Or you need to edit your Hadoop config files to use IP addresses rather than hostnames